How to use Audit Trail module with different entities associated with each other in mendix?
I managed to use mendix Audit trail module with one entity, but couldn't do it with multiple entities. What is the best way to pass multiple entities parameters here ?
I could pass only one object, need to pass multiple object.

According to the documentation, you can do this in two ways:

Make your entity a specialization of the AuditTrailSuperClass. In that case, everything will be handled by an after commit event.
Add a reference set association from your entity to the Log entity or an association from the Log entity to the entity that needs to be audited. Add a before-commit and before-delete event to your entity that is identical to the events on the AudittrailSuperClass. The Java actions will automatically create the log item and all the required log lines based on the changes.

You can read more about the configuration options here in the Mendix documentation.
